# Use dplyr to get index of first column with certain value per group or row

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have the following script. Option 1 uses a long format and `group_by` to identify the first step of many where the status equals 0.

Another option (2) is to use `apply` to calculate this value for each row, and then transform the data to a long format.

The firs option does not scale well. The second does, but I was unable to get it into a `dplyr` pipe. I tried to solve this with `purrr` but did not succeeed.

Questions:

- Why does the first option not scale well?
- How can I transform the second option in a `dplyr` pipe?

```r
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(314)

# example data

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0,1),
                                   size = 9000000, 
                                   replace = TRUE, 
                                   prob = c(5,95)), 
                            ncol = 9))

names(dat) <- paste("step",1:9, sep="_")

steps <- dat %>% select(starts_with("step_")) %>% names()

# option 1 is slow

dat.cum <- dat %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(step, status,-id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(drop = min(if_else(status==0,match(step, steps),99L))) %>%
  mutate(status = if_else(match(step, steps)>=drop,0,1))

ggplot(dat.cum, aes(x = step, fill = factor(status))) +
  geom_bar()

# option 2 is faster

dat$drop <- apply(dat,1,function(x) min(which(x==0),99))

dat.cum <- dat %>%
  gather(step,status,-drop) %>%
  mutate(status = if_else(match(step,steps)>=drop,0,1))

ggplot(dat.cum, aes(x = step, fill = factor(status))) +
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: Second option in a pipe sequence could be `dat %>% mutate(drop = apply(., 1, function(x) min(which(x == 0), 99))) %>% gather(....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to map along rows you could do:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(drop2 = map_int(seq_len(nrow(dat)), ~ min(which(dat[.x, ] == 0L), 99L)))
```

It could be that "gathering and grouping" is faster than Looping:

```
dat %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(starts_with("step_")) %>%
  mutate(row_nr = row_number()) %>%    
  gather(key = "col", value = "value", -row_nr) %>%
  arrange(row_nr, col) %>%
  group_by(row_nr) %>%
  mutate(col_index = row_number()) %>%
  filter(value == 0) %>%
  summarise(drop3 = min(col_index)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(dat %>%
               mutate(row_nr = row_number()), 
             by = "row_nr") %>%
  mutate(drop3 = if_else(is.na(drop3), 99, drop3))
```